# Are there any equations that describe the traditional Prisoner's Dilemma?

Tags: functions, continuity

I want to know if there is a formula or set of formulas for the traditional prisoners dilemma that can be extended to inputs that aren't integers. The traditional prisoners dilemma is, for $T>R>P>S$, $T=3$, $R=2$, $P=1$, and $S=0$, and if a defects and be cooperates, a gets no years in prison and b gets 3, if both defect, both get 2 years in prison, and if both cooperate, they both get 1 year in prison. Is there a formula, that is differentiable at all points between 0 and 1, and that also can have different values for $T$, $R$, $P$, and $S$? Specifically, I want a formula or a set of formulas that takes in two numbers, $a$ and $b$, that for 0=defecting and 1=cooperating, and then if both are 1, all of the formulas output 2, if $a$ is 1 and $b$ is 0, the formula or set of formulas output 3 for $b$, and 0 for $a$, and vice versa if $a$ and $b$ are 0 and 1, and if the formula or set of formulas receive 0 for $a$ and $b$, it outputs 1 for both of them, subject to the earlier restrictions. I want to know because I want to see if I can code a floating point prisoners dilemma, and because I think it'd be interesting. I've tried a few things, with $2-a\times2, 2-b\times2$ and $3-a+1, 3-b+1$ being a few of them. These meet the differentiable requirement (being linear equations), but neither of them work if $a$ and $b$ are different.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking... a formula for _what_?

Comment: Please spare this new contributor some trouble. They are new and do not know the website that well. Please take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), and read the [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). They have an interesting question, but should include more context and their attempts a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two players, so you need two formulas. Let $a$ be the probability that player one cooperates, and $b$ be the probability that player two cooperates. The first formula represents the expected score for player one, and is
$$
\text{Player 1 expected score: }\quad ab\cdot R+(1-a)b\cdot T+a(1-b)\cdot S+(1-a)(1-b)\cdot P
$$
This is just the law of total expectation; both players cooperate with probability $a\cdot b$, in which case player one receives $R$, etc. The other formula for player two is similar, but with $T$ and $S$ switched:
$$
\text{Player 2 expected score: }\quad ab\cdot R+(1-a)b\cdot S+a(1-b)\cdot T+(1-a)(1-b)\cdot P
$$

Comment: Thank you Mike Earnest!